# Various stackid-openid failures on various SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-openid

I decided to migrate a great number of my SE sites to using StackID. I got a lot of errors on various sites.

When I then went to my profile, it just showed "StackExchange" without any username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're working on some back-end changes to network accounts that caused an issue here...I'll build in a moment with a fix for the issue you're seeing.

*Update:* this is deployed, you should now be able to associate without any issues.